# iOS equivalent of Android Application Record, to launch specific app on both platforms?

Tags: android, ios, nfc

Objective: user can tap NFC tag with iPhone or Android and both will prompt to open within the specific app. e.g. it will launch directly into Instagram, agnostic of platform.

From what I understand, this is achieved on Android with AARs and on iphone with app specific URIs such as "instagram://...". Is there a platform agnostic way of achieving this?